# Best practices for Service/Repository pattern and async await APIs

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, repository-pattern

I am pretty much new using Service/Repository pattern. This is the code I have so far:

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAll();
}


public interface IUserRepository : IRepository<User>
{

}


public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
    {
        public async Task<IEnumerable<User>> GetAll()
        {
            List<User> lst = new List<User>();
            lst.Add(new User { ID = 1, Code = "001", Username = "dfrancisco", Password = "dfrancisco123" });
            lst.Add(new User { ID = 1, Code = "002", Username = "111", Password = "1231!" });
            lst.Add(new User { ID = 1, Code = "003", Username = "22", Password = "asdasd1!" });
            lst.Add(new User { ID = 1, Code = "004", Username = "334", Password = "asdasd1" });
            lst.Add(new User { ID = 1, Code = "005", Username = "55", Password = "13" });

            return lst;
        }
    }


public class UserService : IUserService
    {
        private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;

        #region Constructors

        /// <summary>
        /// constructor for UserService
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="UserRepository"></param>
        public UserService(IUserRepository UserRepository)
        {
            _userRepository = UserRepository;
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<UserDTO>> GetAll()
        {
            List<User> data = (await _userRepository.GetAll()).ToList();


            List<UserDTO> dtos = new List<UserDTO>();
            foreach (User item in data)
            {
                dtos.Add(new UserDTO { Username = item.Username });
            }

            return dtos;
           // throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

So, I wanted to know if this es the correct approach to use such a design pattern. I have seen many examples online using this code to return data in this kind of methods :

```
return await _repository.GetAll(eppPlanId);
```

Or this ..

```
return await Task.Run(() => eppPlanDetails);
```

The case I propose is just to demonstrate a random business logic required. So, I would like to understand what are the differences in these approaches and what is the one I should use.

Comment: Well normally `GetAll()` for example would be returning a `Task` because it is typically reading from a database/disk/network asynchonously.  Your code is marked as `async Task` but no task is being created.

Comment: Seems correct for me, only change I want to propose to "hide" Repository implementation details from service - make DTO mapping inside Repository implementation

Comment: Then line `return await Task.Run(() => eppPlanDetails);` where `eppPlanDetails` is asynchronous method - is not good, you will waste a thread for asynchronous method, which can be executed asynchronously on one thread with `await eppPlanDetails`

Comment: Why not use Entity Framework? It is an implementation of the Repository / Unit of Work patterns.

Comment: What Stephen Cleary said. Also generic repository is an anti pattern, and non parametised `getAll()` is code smell. If you want to abstract from ORM impl "just incase" you need to change it. Don't. If you want to do it because it makes testing easier. Use ORM's built in testing. A better abstraction would be something, I call it a `Store`, that contains your specialised methods such as `getUserByUserId(..)`. Impl of this is then concerned with how it gets the actual data, and doesn't suffer from methods you will never use in each `Store`... IMHO, anyway ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you plan to, and you probably should, stick with async APIs, you should have them for all repository APIs too. There is a naming convention in place, to suffix async methods with "Async". So your method should be named as "GetAllAsync()" instead.

As for which approach to stick with - it pretty much comes to the point, whether the API is async or not. If the API is async (in your case it is), you don't need to call Task.Run() any more: just use await when calling the API.
You would use Task.Run in case the GetAll() would be non-async, and would return the IEnumerable directly. In that case, to not block the thread - you'd spin up that work on a different Task using Task.Run.